# Selenium & Scrapy: Last URL overwrites other URLs

Tags: selenium, scrapy, web-crawler

I am currently trying to crawl data from three websites (three different URLs). Therefore, I am using a text-file to load the different URLs into the start_url. 
At the moment, there are three URLs in my file. However, the script just saves/overwrites the data of the two URLs before.

This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy import Spider
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from time import sleep
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import re
import csv

class AlltipsSpider(Spider):
    name = 'alltips'
    allowed_domains = ['blogabet.com']

    def start_requests(self):

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')    
        with open("urls.txt", "rt") as f:
            start_urls = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
        for url in start_urls:
            self.driver.get(url)

            self.driver.find_element_by_id('currentTab').click()
            sleep(3)
            self.logger.info('Sleeping for 5 sec.')
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_blog-menu"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/a[3]').click()
            sleep(7)
            self.logger.info('Sleeping for 7 sec.')
            yield Request(self.driver.current_url, callback=self.crawltips)     

    def crawltips(self, response):
        sel = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
        allposts = sel.xpath('//*[@class="block media _feedPick feed-pick"]')

        for post in allposts:
            username = post.xpath('.//div[@class="col-sm-7 col-lg-6 no-padding"]/a/@title').extract()
            publish_date = post.xpath('.//*[@class="bet-age text-muted"]/text()').extract()


            yield{'Username': username,
                'Publish date': publish_date
                }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the script just saves/overwrites the data of the two URLs before"? It only runs on the last url?

Comment: On each URL the crawler has to crawl 10 different datapoints. So in total the output json file should have 30 datapoints - 10 each for a single URL. Unfortunately, the output file has 30 datapoints but it these datapoints are all from the last URL (3 times 10 the same)

Comment: I think the problem is the following: At the moment, it opens the first URL and makes it clicks. Then, it opens the second and third URL and makes the clicks again. Finally, it goes into the function "crawltips" and crawls the third URL three times. But not the first and second URL.

Comment: I think I got it; can you post the part of the code that collects the datapoints and saves to csv?

Comment: I am not 100 percent sure what you mean: I am just typing "scrapy crawl alltips -o file.csv" into the console.

Comment: Have you had a look at https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium?